# SpeechSynthesis API onend callback not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis, google-text-to-speech

I'm using the [Speech Synthesis API](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/speech-api/raw-file/tip/speechapi.html#tts-section) on Google Chrome v34.0.1847.131. The API is implemented in Chrome starting in v33.

The text-to-speech works for the most part, except when assigning a callback to `onend`. For instance, the following code:

```
var message = window.SpeechSynthesisUtterance("Hello world!");
message.onend = function(event) {
    console.log('Finished in ' + event.elapsedTime + ' seconds.');
};
window.speechSynthesis.speak(message);
```

will sometimes call `onend` and sometimes not call it. The timing appears to be completely off. When it does get called, the printed `elapsedTime` is always some epoch time like `1399237888`.

Comment: just because specs are written at w3...doesn't mean they work or work exactly like that in all browsers especially if they are new and experimental like speechsynthesis..not that this capability is some sort of technological breakthrough but it's first time to be brought to browsers.

Comment: I checked what you were doing and yes the problem exists...for me on end event hasn't fired even once...and onstart misses sometimes too.

Comment: Thanks for checking. It's encouraging to see someone else with this issue. I guess this might just be a half-baked implementation, so this question may not have an answer.

Comment: check this out...for some weird reason if you log out the utterance object `message` then it works fine. :D
http://jsfiddle.net/QYw6b/

Comment: Wow, that's interesting. The `event.elapsedTime` is still bunk, but `onend` appears to be firing off every single time.

Comment: in fact i think problem is calling the speak function right away after declaring message object is the problem..if you just do this `
setTimeout(function(){speechSynthesis.speak(u);},100);` it works...or attack speak function to click event it works fine too.

Comment: `setTimeout(function(){speechSynthesis.speak(u);},1);` works as well and is indistinguishable from just calling it straight. Seems that the API only likes to live inside of a callback. Would love some more insight into why this is the behavior we're observing, but probably only Googlers know for sure. If you'd like, you can write up an answer to this question with the information you've provided and I'll give it its due credit :)

Comment: i am also able to get time

Comment: I still see this on chrome v46 for Windows.  I don't recall it happening on Chrome for android.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While this is how I found it to make it work, I am not sure if this is the right behavior....

First don't call the speak function it right away, use callback.

2nd, to get time use `timeStamp` instead of `elapsedTime`. You could have just used `performance.now()` as well.

```
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
speechSynthesis.cancel()
var u = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
u.text = "This text was changed from the original demo.";

var t;
u.onstart = function (event) {
    t = event.timeStamp;
    console.log(t);
};

u.onend = function (event) {
    t = event.timeStamp - t;
    console.log(event.timeStamp);
    console.log((t / 1000) + " seconds");
};

btn.onclick = function () {speechSynthesis.speak(u);};
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QYw6b/2/

you get time passed and both events fired for sure.

Comment: although it does works this example, as soon as you use a non-english voice, it stops triggering the onend event.

Answer (score 26):

According to [this comment](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=509488#c11) on the bug mentioned in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34844998/109663) from Kevin Hakanson, it might be a problem with garbage collection. Storing the utterance in a variable before calling `speak` [seems to do the trick](https://jsfiddle.net/pilyugin/dgygqLw2/):

```
window.utterances = [];
var utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance( 'hello' );
utterances.push( utterance );
speechSynthesis.speak( utterance );
```

Comment: Thanks for this!  Once I changed the scope my utterance variable I didn't have the issue anymore.  I agree that there might be a bug related to the browser's internal GC.

Comment: Worked! To make it clear for beginners like me, making the scope of the `SpeechSynthesisUtterance` variable broader, e.g. global, does the trick.

Comment: What is the push doing? and what is utterances?

Comment: `utterances` is an array created in the first line. `push` adds an item to the end of an array: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: This solution didn't work for me.  My scenario is that i am a calling my `speak_please()` function from within the `onend` callback (so calling `speak_please()` from within `speak_please()`), and it's not waiting for the speaking to end before calling `speak_please()` -  it just calls it immediately so it is iterating through all divs until the end at lightening speed.  Chrome Version 75.0.3770.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Actually, I think my issue is that `onend` is not just fired when an utterance "naturally" comes to an end, but also after `synth.cancel()` so every time i cancel an utterance, I trigger `onend` to occur - thus i rapidly create and cancel multiple utterances until there are no divs left.

Comment: nice one man! storing just the current utterance on global `window` and removing it once all speaking is done — works perfect for me!

Answer (score 6):

You could use the EventListener for start and end like I did for Speakerbot (**http://www.speakerbot.de/**).

Here my face changes while words are spoken.

```
newUtt = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();

newUtt.addEventListener('start', function () {
     console.log('started');
})

newUtt.addEventListener('end', function () {
     console.log('stopped');
})
```

Answer (score 4):

I found both solutions suggested here not working in [an app I just wrote](http://tabellin.ga/). The only solution I could come up with is a (sort of) busy waiting:

```
function speak( text, onend ) {
  window.speechSynthesis.cancel();
  var ssu = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance( text );
  window.speechSynthesis.speak( ssu );
  function _wait() {
    if ( ! window.speechSynthesis.speaking ) {
      onend();
      return;
    }
    window.setTimeout( _wait, 200 );
  }
  _wait();
}
```

you can find a complete example in [this codepen](http://codepen.io/mapio/pen/dYxNxx?editors=101)

Comment: I like how you start the function by calling `cancel()` and that solves my problem. Though for me `speechSynthesis.speaking` is true far longer than it should be, so the busy waiting isn't useful for me.

Answer (score 3):

This looks similar to a Chromium bug reported on Jul 12, 2015.

> Issue [509488](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=509488): Web Speech API: 'end' event of SpeechSynthesisUtterance object is not dispatched sometimes

Answer (score 1):

print the utterance before speak seems working...
If I remove the console, this issue will happen, don't know why

```
console.log("utterance", utterThis);
synth.speak(utterThis);
```

Answer (score 0):

I also found the only way to make this work reliably is to use .cance.  I use a 17 second timeout. All of my recordings are under 20 seconds so this works for me.

```
utterance.onstart = function (event) {
setTimeout(function(){window.speechSynthesis.cancel();},17000);
};
```

Before I would run into this problem once every 8-10 messages it attempted. Once I added .cancel it seems to always work. I also call set timeout when invoking.

```
setTimeout(function(){window.speechSynthesis.speak(utterance);},100);
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me was to avoid voices with `localService` being `true`. Those voices never fired `onend` while the other voices (localService being false) did fire `onend`.

Answer (score 0):

Also, on Chrome (but not Safari), the callback is never called if you try to speak an empty string.